# How to compile jnativehook?

Tags: java, ant

I can't use English well but I got problem.
I'm using 'jnativehook global mouse/keyboard listener' library on my program.
But when I press quit button on my program, it didn't terminated because of jnativehook's thread. So I need set setDaemon true to it's source. I found that code and changed setDaemon method parameter to 'true'. So I proceeded
 to build using 'ant' what it written on developer's page. I added JNITasks's jar file in the source folder. But I got this error when I build.[image]. What do I have to do to build it.
And line 345 in build.xml file is below picture[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need more of the error message, but I suspect that you did not put JNITasks.jar in the root of the project.  Download v0.2 here https://github.com/kwhat/jnitasks/releases

Comment: Thank you ver much. I downloaded the link and added it to source folder. It works properly. I'm very thanks to you to answer me and made this great library as open source. It's super useful to me. Thanks a lot!!